# How do I create Private channel between two user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, websocket, faye, private-pub

I have been implementing `Faye` server for chat application. Currently we have 400000 users in our table. Each user can chat with one another privately. But I don’t know how to implement private channel between two users using `Faye` or `private pub` for 4 lakhs user. Do I have to make a table which will contain around `4 lakhs X 4 lakhs` private channel entry, I think that is not a good idea. please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Faye documentation provides some very good information on this subject:
http://faye.jcoglan.com/security.html

In your case the *How should I authenticate clients?* is particularly relevant.

The users who are to participate in the private one-to-one chat [subscribe to a channel](http://faye.jcoglan.com/browser/subscribing.html) and your application controls who can subscribe to that channel using the authentication techniques mentioned - it only allows the two expected users to participate.